# Any javascript method like php "glob" to get filenames or directories that match the specified pattern?

Tags: javascript, search

I am a newbie of javascript and I would like to create very simple web apps

I order to get filenames or directories that match the specified pattern.
I can using glob in php

`glob("*.txt")`

How about javascript?? Thank you very much

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob

Answer (score 0):

Either `Array.every()` or you can do a custom `Array.map()` with conditioners. You do need to supply a list of names though as it's tough doing with vanilla JS because of security reasons..